# JavaFX setMaximized(true) not working with StageStyle.UNDECORATED on Ubuntu

Tags: java, javafx

I created a full screen app using JavaFX without title bar but it only successfully launched on full screen mode on Windows. When I tried on Linux (Ubuntu 19.04 Disco Dingo), the full screen mode can not works without title bar. Any clue to solve the issue?

```
package mrs;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class Mrs extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        primaryStage.setMaximized(true);

        /*If i comment this 1 line below,
            I can run the app in full screen mode on Ubuntu,
            but the tittle bar stil exist*/
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);

        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green;");

        Scene s = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(s);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: What java version are you using and what JavaFX version are you using?

Comment: You could try setting maximized after the stage shows. I don't use linux for FX though, so it's just a guess.

Comment: @Abra I'm using version 8.0.212

Comment: @Jai still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I found the solution on another StackOverflow thread.

Finally I can displaying full screen app without title bar on Linux using setFullScreen and setFullScreenExitKeyCombination(KeyCombination.NO_MATCH)